# How can I hide the primary menu block to certain pages using PHP?

Tags: theming, hooks

I tried this code to hide the primary menu block from certain pages using the following code:

```
// Only show block from types array and nodes array
$match = FALSE;
// Which node types
$types = array('page' => 1);
// Which nodes (by nid)
$nodes = array(1, 13);
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid = arg(1);
  $node = node_load(array('nid' => $nid));
  $type = $node->type;
  if (isset($types[$type]) && in_array($nid, $nodes)) {
        $match = TRUE;
  }
}
return $match;
```

Currently, the block is set to visible in the header section of the site; the theme being used  is the Bluemarine theme.

Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Print Screen

[image: Print Screen]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6y4I.jpg

Menu Print Screem

[image: Menu Print Screem]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUBD2.jpg

Comment: Don't use arg(1) to load the node, trust the API and use menu_get_object(). http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/6. Also, why is this tagged as "drupal-theming", block visibility is not a theming concern, or at least it shouldn't be.

Comment: can you show how to use menu_get_object() with the above code ?

Comment: "if ($node = menu_get_object()) { ...do something with $node... }" instead of "if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) { $nid = arg(1); $node = node_load(array('nid' => $nid)); ...do something with $node... }".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it from the block configuration

1. go to admin/build/block
2. search for the block and click "configure"
3. in the "Page specific visibility settings" click on "Show on only the listed pages"
4. write the page that you want this block to be visible on E.g "news" this will make that block visible on http://www.examble.com/news

Is that what you mean?

**UPDATE:**

if you want to control tha appearance programatically do the following

1- Disable the primary links block from "admin/build/block"

2- enable the primary links menu from your theme configuration (now i suppose you see the menu in all the pages and you want to specify the pages that you want this menu to appear in)

3- open page.tpl.php file

4- go to line 24 you will find something like this

```
<?php if (isset($primary_links)) { ?><?php print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' => 'links', 'id' => 'navlist')) ?><?php } ?>
```

we will edit the following condition **if (isset($primary_links))**

now you should know something if you have url like this
http://yoursite.com/media/pictures

then the function arg(0) will return `media` and arg(1) will return `pictures`

another example

http://yoursite.com/admin

then the function arg(0) will return the first argument in your url which is `admin`

now lets back to the condition `if (isset($primary_links))`

we will edit it ... we wanna say to drupal if the first argument is equal to something then appear the menu else disable the menu

suppose that you want the menu to appeare in the page `user`

then you will edit the `if (isset($primary_links))` to be

`if (isset($primary_links) && (arg(0) == 'user')  )`

suppose that you want this menu to appeare in page `user` and page `admin`

`if (isset($primary_links) && (arg(0) == 'user' || arg(0) == 'admin')  )`

one more advanced example... if you want the menu to appeare only in 
`user/1` page and `admin`  page

`if (isset($primary_links) && ( (arg(0) == 'user' && arg(1) == '1') || arg(0) == 'admin')  )`

hope that will help you

Comment: yes this is exactly what am looking for, but when I put show on listed pages node/1, node/13 (separate lines) still the primary menu block is appearing in all pages, I tried the above code also but still no result ? anything I missed ?

Comment: no you are on the right way .. just clear all the code you have inserted before...make sure that each  path is on a line E.g node/1 in on line one node/13 is on line 2...and so on ... cleare the cache if there is no effect...if u still have the problem try to change the theme to see if the problem in the theme it self or what...(but i dont think its related to the theme)...but try what i told u above

Comment: I had manually removed all records from cache tables from mysql, still the primary link block (visibility set in header section in block page) configured to show in list of pages - <front>, node/1, node/13 list in seperate lines(no comma at end) is still showing in all pages of the site.

Comment: can you attach print screen of ur block configuration please

Comment: I had put the screenshot above ? please let me know whether am correct or not ?

Comment: mmmm u r on the right way... but i think primary links block is not related to the menu that appear in the header...it might be a copy of the menu that appear in the header...so now we need to know if this block "primary link" is related to the menu that you see at the header...can you please disable "primary links" block and tell me if the menu is still exist

Comment: yes even after I select None for primary link menu its showing in site ?
In menu page the primary link contain all the item seen in the image !

Comment: this is what in my theme page.tpl.php. 'code'<div id="headinghm" align="center">
    <?php if (isset($primary_links)) { ?><?php print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' => 'links', 'id' => 'navlist')) ?><?php } ?>
</div>'code'

Comment: ok now its clear that the menu that you see is not a block...we will do more then 1 step....first we wanna tell drupal disable this menu i wanna use my own block "primary links block"... to disable this menu...go to "admin/build/themes/settings/bluemarine" and uncheck "primary links"... now we disabled the primary links menu... lets workiing with blocks....now you should go to "admin/build/block" and enable "primary links" block and control which page you want this block to be displayed on

Comment: ok I will let you know...

Comment: ok I just disable primary menu globaly/bluemarine theme. Back to block primary link block and put show in listed pages, save it. But now there is no primary menu in listed pages and also in other pages ? if I enable bluemmarine theme primary menu its showing up in all pages ! pls help me.

Comment: **hi.. maged adel** is there any need of edit in page.tpl.php ?

Comment: Yes i remember that you have disabled the block...please enable the block and put it in the header secion... no need to edit page.tpl.php...drupal support this functionality

Comment: but now its not showing in any pages ?

Comment: that is once disable from theme, menu is not showing even if it enabled in block admin page. is there anyother steps I missed ?

Comment: no...what i need now is to disable the menu (because we can't control the menu appearance) ... and enable the block that have the same items the menu have (because we can control the blocks appearance)...after enabling the block we have one more step(theming the block to be like the menu).. but i want you now to make sure that the block is enabled and have the items that the menu have..and make sure that you can control the block appearance as you need

Comment: I edited my answer please re check my answer

Comment: ok I will check that, if I wanted $nid in place of user/admin shall I provide the id for content pages ?

Comment: check the advanced example(example number 3)...is that what you mean ?

Comment: yes this worked for me if (isset($primary_links) && (arg(1) == '1' || arg(1) == '13' || arg(1) == '3' || arg(1) == '14' || arg(1) == '6' || arg(1) == '5')). thank u very much maged adel....

Comment: u welcome :) .. but in ur example  don't forget to add  (arg(0) == 'node' ) && (arg(1) == '1' || arg(1) ... etc) .... to avoid appearing the menu if the url like this 'user/1' or 'user/13' .. good luck

Comment: One more thing, if I create a new menu will it come automatically on theme page ? so that I can do same process with different condition to view it on site ?

Comment: its depending on your theme....Bluemarine theme...and the most of drupal themes have two main type of menues... Primary menu and Secondary menu...this 2 menues can be controled  from page.tpl.php....if you have created a new menu from "admin/build/menu".. you will get a new block generated  which you can control the appearance and position of this block

Comment: I created a new menu and from block admin page I configure it to show in list pages - node/11 and make it visisble to header section but its not showing ? can we add this to theme ? Also I want this menu to look same as primary menu, so where should I put style ?

Comment: Your theme can hold only 1 menu in the header which is the Primary menu.... try to add this menu at the right or the left sidebar of your theme

Comment: what I am trying is once the primary menu is visible only in listed pages, is it possible to display a custom menu for another set of pages in same position ?

Comment: I got this link [link]http://www.kleinermann.com.au/blog/add-a-custom-menu-in-drupal-6/[link]. will this help me to add a new menu to bluemarine theme ?

Comment: Hi **maged adel** this [link]http://drupal.org/node/549532 help to add more menus to site  !!! thank you once again sir.